# how to query open PRs that I've reviewed OR I was requested to review

Tags: github

I want to list all the PRs that I was requested to review:

`https://github.com/pulls?q=review-requested%3Abrtbrtis%3Aopen+is%3Apr`

or I reviewed without a request:

`https://github.com/pulls?q=reviewed-by%3Abrtbrt+is%3Aopen+is%3Apr`

Both queries above work, but I can't apply an OR logics to list both at the same time. Is that possible?